# Vectorization - Sum and Bessel function

Tags: matlab, sum, vectorization, nested-loops, bessel-functions

Can anyone help vectorize this Matlab code? The specific problem is the sum and bessel function with vector inputs. 
Thank you!

```
N = 3;
rho_g = linspace(1e-3,1,N);
phi_g = linspace(0,2*pi,N);

n = 1:3;
tau = [1 2.*ones(1,length(n)-1)];
for ii = 1:length(rho_g)
    for jj = 1:length(phi_g)
        % Coordinates
        rho_o = rho_g(ii);
        phi_o = phi_g(jj);
        % factors
        fc = cos(n.*(phi_o-phi_s));
        fs = sin(n.*(phi_o-phi_s));

        Ez_t(ii,jj) = sum(tau.*besselj(n,k(3)*rho_s).*besselh(n,2,k(3)*rho_o).*fc);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Initialization -

```
N = 3;
rho_g = linspace(1e-3,1,N);
phi_g = linspace(0,2*pi,N);

n = 1:3;
tau = [1 2.*ones(1,length(n)-1)];
```

Nested loops form (Copy from your code and shown here for comparison only) -

```
for ii = 1:length(rho_g)
    for jj = 1:length(phi_g)
        % Coordinates
        rho_o = rho_g(ii);
        phi_o = phi_g(jj);
        % factors
        fc = cos(n.*(phi_o-phi_s));
        fs = sin(n.*(phi_o-phi_s));

        Ez_t(ii,jj) = sum(tau.*besselj(n,k(3)*rho_s).*besselh(n,2,k(3)*rho_o).*fc);
    end
end
```

Vectorized solution -

```
%%// Term - 1
term1 = repmat(tau.*besselj(n,k(3)*rho_s),[N*N 1]);

%%// Term - 2
[n1,rho_g1] = meshgrid(n,rho_g);
term2_intm = besselh(n1,2,k(3)*rho_g1);
term2 = transpose(reshape(repmat(transpose(term2_intm),[N 1]),N,N*N));

%%// Term -3
angle1 = repmat(bsxfun(@times,bsxfun(@minus,phi_g,phi_s')',n),[N 1]);
fc = cos(angle1);

%%// Output
Ez_t = sum(term1.*term2.*fc,2);
Ez_t = transpose(reshape(Ez_t,N,N));
```

Points to note about this vectorization or code simplification –

1. ‘fs’ doesn’t change the output of the script, Ez_t, so it could be removed for now.
2. The output seems to be ‘Ez_t’,which requires three basic terms in the code as – 
   **tau.*besselj(n,k(3)*rho_s)**, **besselh(n,2,k(3)*rho_o)** and **fc**. These are calculated separately for vectorization as terms1,2 and 3 respectively.
3. All these three terms appear to be of 1xN sizes. Our aim thus becomes to calculate these three terms without loops. Now, the two loops run for N times each, thus giving us a total loop count of NxN. Thus, we must have NxN times the data in each such term as compared to when these terms were inside the nested loops.
4. This is basically the essence of the vectorization done here, as the three terms are represented by ‘term1’,’term2’ and ‘fc’ itself.

Answer (score 1):

You could try to vectorize this code, which might be possible with some `bsxfun` or so, but it would be hard to understand code, and it is the question if it would run any faster, since your code already uses vector math in the inner loop (even though your vectors only have length 3). The resulting code would become very difficult to read, so you or your colleague will have no idea what it does when you have a look at it in 2 years time.

Before wasting time on vectorization, it is much more important that you learn about [loop invariant code motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion), which is easy to apply to your code. Some observations:

- you do not use `fs`, so remove that.
- the term `tau.*besselj(n,k(3)*rho_s)` does not depend on any of your loop variables `ii` and `jj`, so it is constant. Calculate it once before your loop.
- you should probably pre-allocate the matrix `Ez_t`.
- the only terms that change during the loop are `fc`, which depends on `jj`, and `besselh(n,2,k(3)*rho_o)`, which depends on `ii`. I guess that the latter costs much more time to calculate, so it better to not calculate this `N*N` times in the inner loop, but only `N` times in the outer loop. If the calculation based on `jj` would take more time, you could swap the for-loops over `ii` and `jj`, but that does not seem to be the case here.

The result code would look something like this (untested):

```
N = 3;
rho_g = linspace(1e-3,1,N);
phi_g = linspace(0,2*pi,N);

n = 1:3;
tau = [1 2.*ones(1,length(n)-1)];

% constant part, does not depend on ii and jj, so calculate only once!
temp1 = tau.*besselj(n,k(3)*rho_s); 

Ez_t = nan(length(rho_g), length(phi_g)); % preallocate space
for ii = 1:length(rho_g)
    % calculate stuff that depends on ii only
    rho_o = rho_g(ii);
    temp2 = besselh(n,2,k(3)*rho_o);

    for jj = 1:length(phi_g)
        phi_o = phi_g(jj);
        fc = cos(n.*(phi_o-phi_s));
        Ez_t(ii,jj) = sum(temp1.*temp2.*fc);
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to give a self-contained answer, I'll copy the original initialization

```
N = 3;
rho_g = linspace(1e-3,1,N);
phi_g = linspace(0,2*pi,N);

n = 1:3;
tau = [1 2.*ones(1,length(n)-1)];
```

and generate some missing data (k(3) and rho_s and phi_s in the dimension of n)

```
rho_s = rand(size(n));
phi_s = rand(size(n));
k(3) = rand(1);
```

then you can compute the same Ez_t with multidimensional arrays:

```
[RHO_G, PHI_G, N] = meshgrid(rho_g, phi_g, n);
[~, ~, TAU] = meshgrid(rho_g, phi_g, tau);
[~, ~, RHO_S] = meshgrid(rho_g, phi_g, rho_s);
[~, ~, PHI_S] = meshgrid(rho_g, phi_g, phi_s);

FC = cos(N.*(PHI_G - PHI_S));
FS = sin(N.*(PHI_G - PHI_S)); % not used

EZ_T = sum(TAU.*besselj(N, k(3)*RHO_S).*besselh(N, 2, k(3)*RHO_G).*FC, 3).';
```

You can check afterwards that both matrices are the same

```
norm(Ez_t - EZ_T)
```